# Stop printing warning message "Using CPU. Note: This module is much faster with a GPU."

Tags: python, easyocr

I am running a Python program using the excellent EasyOCR module. It relies on PyTorch for image detection and every time I run it, it produces a warning: "*Using CPU. Note: This module is much faster with a GPU.*" for each iteration.

What can I add to my code to stop this output without stopping other output? I don't have a GPU so that is not an option.

Answer (score 7):

After looking into the [source code](https://github.com/JaidedAI/EasyOCR/blob/7a685cb8c4ba14f2bc246f89c213f1a56bbc2107/easyocr/easyocr.py#L69), I noticed that `verbose` is set to `True` by default in the constructor.

After setting `verbose=False` the message stops appearing.

```py
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'], gpu=False, verbose=False)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think there is a command line parameter --gpu=false. Have you tried that?

Comment: I use it regularly and unfortunately it does not stop the warning message.